# Avoid sql_variant but use what?

Tags: sql, database, sql-variant

My database holds template forms and real forms having values. Users will be able to create custom template forms with different types of fields. I will keep values in a separate table.

Forms table:

```
Id | Name | TemplateId
```

FormFields table:

```
Id | FormId | Name | ValueType (nvchar)
```

Values Table

```
FieldId | Value
```

When user designs a form it is saved into forms table having TemplateId `NULL`. Also FormFields table stores the fields that will be used for this form.
Later when user creates a *real* form using that template, the real values of this form (derieved from FormFields) will be stored in Values table.
Now, the value column in Values table seems to be `sql_variant` type. If I don't use `sql_variant` how can I solve this problem?

Ps: What about creating different tables for each kind of values? TableIntValues, TableBoolValues etc?

http://www.jotform.com/ can be a good sample for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using separate columns for the separate data types, along these lines:

```
FieldId | StringValue | IntegerValue  |  DateTimeValue
```

That way you can have queries run over the data sensibly, and also keep it type safe.  You would obviously need logic to ensure that the data gets populated correctly, and a constraint to ensure only one column is populated and not all are NULL.

Comment: Thanks. Is that a general solution or just an idea?

Comment: There may be intricacies in your application that will mean the above pattern falls down, but I have used it successfully for similar work.